# How to read text from a file and encode it to be represented correctly? (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, character-encoding

I have a .step file where Russian letters displayed incorrectly (203 ñòåï ÒÖÍÐ.466219.007 Èíòåðàêòèâíûé êîìïëåêñ). How could I read this Russian text from a file, store it in a string or in a char array, and fix it to be displayed correctly? (203 степ ТЦНР.466219.007 Интерактивный комплекс NextPanel 43/NAUO255). I tried to use ICONV to encode the text to UTF-8 from Windows-1251, but the result is still a mess. When I check the file encoding on windows 11 (Notepad - it shows me that the encoding is UTF-8, when I open the same file on Ubuntu, it shows that the encoding is ISO-8859-1). By the way, I need the encoded text to be store in a variable, to put it in my GTKMM application.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JeP9HKIer-rc7c0CJyRh_Ykjf3t5zHuh?usp=sharing
.STEP file (May be halpful)

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of the file is in the Windows-1251 character set? If you look at it in a hex-editor, do the characters correspond to Windows-1251? And how do you currently "display" the file contents?

Comment: Looks like a case of [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: Before you delve into `wchar_t` and [the localizations library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale), one obvious thing to check are your terminal + locale settings. With a properly configured UTF-8 terminal, you can handle UTF-8 strings with just a `std::string`, as if they were old good (well, in fact bad) 8-bit strings. `std::string` doesn’t care and passes UTF-8 through just fine. The terminal will then interpret the multi-byte UTF-8 characters, if properly configured to do so. (On reasonable systems this is the case by default, UTF-8 everywhere.)

Comment: Currently I am displaying the file context in a particular GTKMM container - I put the text into the container and show it in he application. I am not sure if the file encoding is Windows-1251, but one programmer sad me that it is

Comment: I dont care about displaying the text in the terminal. I am more interested in displaying the text in the application

Comment: `echo '203 ñòåï ÒÖÍÐ.466219.007 Èíòåðàêòèâíûé êîìïëåêñ' | iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252 | iconv -f windows-1251 -t utf-8`

Comment: The small portion I checked was Windows 1251.

Comment: Notepad++ also reports it as Windows 1251, and I've only known Notepad++ to be wrong once.